# Copying an image to pasteboard transcodes jpeg to png

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, copy-paste, uipasteboard

I'm working on an iPhone app to embed/extract data in jpeg files.  I want to give the user the ability to copy the resulting image to the clipboard, but the code I'm using coverts the resulting jpeg into a png when it gets copied to the clipboard.

I'm using the code below, is there anything I can do to ensure it is a bit by bit copy and paste of the jpeg?

```
// copy to clipboard
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
pasteboard.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"output.jpg"];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured this one out.

```
// copy to clipboard
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
[pasteboard setData:data forPasteboardType:@"public.jpeg"];
```

...

```
// copy from clipboard
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSData *data = [pasteboard dataForPasteboardType:@"public.jpeg"];
NSString  *copyPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/image.jpg"];
[data writeToFile:copyPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Hey Ben, I use this too, but I found out that whatever pulls the image off the pasteboard turns it back into a png. Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, I missed this comment...Anyway how are you pulling it off the clipboard?  I never had any problems with that.  I can post the code to retrieve it later when I find my code.

Comment: Hi Ben. This is the code we tried to push a jpg. I assume it did, but it always seems to come back out into email and iMessage as a png.                                                                  UIImage* jpeg = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img,0.2)];
        [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setValue:[UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img,0.5)] forPasteboardType:@"public.jpeg"];

Answer (score -1):

```
NSPasteboard *pboard  = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pboard declareTypes: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:
                       NSTIFFPboardType] owner: nil];
[pboard setData:[imgView.image TIFFRepresentation] forType:NSTIFFPboardType];

NSData *data = [[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard] dataForType:NSPasteboardTypeTIFF];
    if (data) {
           // Do your stuff here 
    }
```

Completely working code ,  i m using same code

Good Luck !!!!

Comment: Not to mention the question wanted to use JPEG, not TIFF.